# Did Dobby do a "camera-take?"

Tags: harry-potter, movie, dobby

In [Harry Potter and The Chamber of Secrets](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0295297/), Lucius Malfoy enters Dumbledore's office with Dobby. Harry is already present. But when Dobby begins to walk to the stairs leading to Dumbledore's desk, it looks like he glances towards where the camera and crew would be, were he not a CG-created creature.

It happens at about 2 hours and 21 minutes in.
*(Sorry, I'm not 100% sure if I owned the PAL or NTSC DVD when I ripped this to my hard drive; time may be a few minutes off for other coding.)*

[image: Don't look at Frank Booth]

> <sup><sub>I've never been a fan of Dobby. Mostly, he just annoys me. This moment "humanizes" him and makes me feel a bit of empathy.</sub></sup>

I was wondering if I read too much into this glance, or if it was a way to make the "performer" seem more insecure and thus more "real." Has anyone else noticed this, and if so, **has this been addressed in any interviews, Easter eggs, or behind the scenes bits?**

It seemed *odd* on first viewing, and I've never gotten used to it. If they made Dobby intentionally break the fourth wall, that's pretty interesting and *clever*. Otherwise, I'm not sure why he'd be glancing in that direction during the shot.

I've seen CGI creations do "bloopers and out-takes" (Pixar, I think) but those were obviously jokes and were not as compelling or unsettling as it happening during a movie in a *dramatic* scene.

Comment: surely Dobby is just looking around the office, taking in his surroundings in wonderment? Personal opinion.

Comment: Sorry, but no. If you **watch** the scene, he's not *looking around the office,* unless looking around means looking at one spot. He just looks at this one spot above the camera (where a crew would presumably be) when not looking at his Master. I suggest you check it out. It's very surreal once you notice it. I happened to notice it on first viewing and it's become a weirdness I can't *not* notice.

Comment: I'll watch the scene later, but I think it's just something that you thought was a bit odd, and now you reinforce it every time you watch it. It's entirely possible that he is just looking at a headmaster portrait (Although I can't find any record of a Malfoy being a headmaster).

Comment: He does not just look at the one spot.  As he is running toward the stairs, he first looks to his right, then he turns to look to his left.  This look to his left is what you are referencing.

Comment: @JohnP I tried to address that I may be reading into it in the OP, but also, I never saw him look to his right like Paul suggests, just at Malfoy, then to his left.

Comment: Can’t say I remember this offhand, nor the exact layout of Dumbledore’s office… but could he perhaps be staring at Fawkes? Would the direction fit? A phoenix would probably be something that would make even a house elf stare a bit.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, Fawkes was by Albus' desk in this scene. I couldn't find anything to look at there in this scene other than the camera and crew. I'm not saying that's what it **is,** but it looks like it.

Comment: I always took it that he was looking at Harry. That the camera was placed in Harry's eyes. I admit that I never bothered to check the disposition of the room. Where would harry be compared to Dobby's position in that picture?

Comment: Harry was up by Dumbledore's desk. When Dobby entered, he did look forward to make eye-contact with Harry.

Answer (score 3):

I recall that scene, and I always saw it as a look of nervousness or insecurity. Remember, his master is Lucius Malfoy. No doubt Dobby was always looking over his shoulder. I highly doubt they would have Dobby look at the camera, considering the time and effort to animate something like that.

Comment: It would take exactly the same amount of time and effort to animate. All it takes is a plan, like any other, then the animation.

Comment: Exactly. It isn't going to take any noticeable difference in effort to have Dobby look in location A vs location B. Unless I'm understanding the answer.